# PHP call_user_func & $class->$func()

Tags: php

RT

function 1 :

```
$class->$func()
```

function 2:

```
//Simple callback
call_user_func($func)
//Static class method call
call_user_func(array($class,$func))
//Object method call
$class = new MyClass();
call_user_func(array($class, $func));
```

Is there a difference? I want to see the sourcecode(https://github.com/php/php-src) should we do?

Comment: There's no differences in the ways you've presented of calling an object method. What's your question anyway?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) is very slow performance-wise, that's why in many cases you want to go with explicit method call. But, sometimes you want to pass arbitrary number of arguments passed as an array, e.g.

```
public function __call($name, $args) {
    $nargs = sizeof($args);
    if ($nargs == 0) {
        $this->$name();
    }
    elseif ($nargs == 1) { 
        $this->$name($args[0]);
    }
    elseif ($nargs == 2) { 
        $this->$name($args[0], $args[1]);
    }
    #...
    // you obviously can't go through $nargs = 0..10000000, 
    // so at some point as a last resort you use call_user_func_array
    else { 
        call_user_func_array(array($this,$name), $args);
    }
}
```

I'd go with checking `$nargs` up to 5 (it's usually unlikely that a function in PHP accepts more than 5 arguments, so in most cases we will call a method directly without using `call_user_func_array` which is good for performance)

The result of `$class->method($arg)` is the same as `call_user_func_array(array($class,'method'), array($arg))`, but the first one is faster.